# How to add a page into Cambridge Phd Latex template?

Tags: templates

I want to add a page called "Approval" into my dissertation right before the 'Abstract' page. I am using the Cambridge Phd Latex format.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  Please share your initial attempt at producing the document, a minimal example of your LaTeX code here.

Comment: `\clearpage <some content> \clearpage` inserts a new page containing `<some content>` in every context. And by "called" you mean "containing the word" or "with the title"?

Comment: I am using version 2.1 https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/releases/tag/v2.1

Comment: Sorry, I am new here and messed up a bit.

Comment: Personally i cannot recommend that templates, as it gives the advice to ignore warnings. You should never ignore any warning signs.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the file `thesis.tex`, the main file for the thesis, supported by the class `PhDThesisPSnPDF`.

There you will find:

```
\include{Dedication/dedication}
\include{Declaration/declaration}
\include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement}
\include{Abstract/abstract}
```

With a little bit searching inside the code you can find a definition for environment `acknowledgements`:

```
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{
\cleardoublepage
\setsinglecolumn
\chapter*{\centering \Large Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{empty}
}
```

You can copy it and change it to that what you need:

```
\newenvironment{approval}{
\cleardoublepage
\setsinglecolumn
\chapter*{\centering \Large Approval}
\thispagestyle{empty}
}
```

Add this into your preambel of `thesis.tex` (before command `\begin{document}`) and add some content for your  `approval`:

```
...
\include{Dedication/dedication}
\include{Declaration/declaration}
\include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement}

\begin{approval}
This is where you write your Approval ...
\end{approval}

\include{Abstract/abstract}
...
```

I have not installed that class so the code above is untest, but I think it should compile.  Please try it and report the result.